# Cleanup Google Mobile Backend Starter

Tags: google-app-engine

So I started to play with [Google Mobile Backend Starter](https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/).

Now I want to clean this instance and anything that this starter thingy created into the project (e.g. task queues, data store, etc...)

How do we achieve this?

Is this done through some command line somewhere along the lines described in [this page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp)?

```
appengine-java-sdk/bin
```

**EDIT:** I should have made it clearer, I don't intend to delete the project. I just want to "clean" it and replace with my own application. Anyway, I ended up using the appengine SDK tools mentioned above (*[Updating and Managing a Java App](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp)*). It was a long process, and tedious. It could be improved.

What I did:

- Using the appengine SDK tool, downloaded the application first. It prompted me for a password. I had to create a new "App Password" entry in my Google account, since it didn't accept my "usual" Google password (e.g. GMAIL)
- To clean the Scheduled Tasks, edit *cron.xml* so that no entries are left. A sample empty cron.xml file is shown in the [documentation page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron#Java_appengine_web_xml_Uploading_cron_jobs). Run the update procedure of the SDK tool for cron jobs
- To clean the Queues, use the same approach (*queue.xml*)
- Clean DataStore by going to [DataStore Admin](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin#Deleting_Entities_in_Bulk) page (if applicable)
- Upload your new application (either thru SDK, or thru Android/Eclipse AppEngine plugin)
- There will now be 2 (or more) versions of your AppEngine. If necessary, make your newly uploaded application, the default version. This is done in the Developer Console.
- Check the instances as well. Remove if necessary